# Redirecting http to https results in www.https//mywebsite.com

Tags: http, redirect, https, web-config

I am trying to redirect http:// to https:// using this code:

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
 </rewrite>
```

So when I go to:
[www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) it goes to http://www.mywebsite.com as expected,

but when I type it as:
mywebsite.com (without www) it goes to www.https//mywebsite.com (with a "This site can't be reached" error)

How can I correct this?

Please help.

TIA

Comment: `{REQUEST_URI}` is the full URL including everything. because you use this you are getting this problem. BTW: You forgot to mention the used server, therefore you won't get a real answer.

Comment: @Robert, I am using Windows Server 2016, is that what you mean? What can I use instead of {REQUEST_URI} or should I just remove it?